# How to assign values to 2 dimensional array in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I want to assign the result of this code into a 2D array, I tried to save the result from the first output of the program in a file, and later on I will re open the file to assign the values in to the array, so I can use the array to get the result of the distance function…Unfortunately, when I defined the array as “int data[100][2]” Ican’t use the “getline(myfile,line)”…because its work with a string values not int,
is there any other way to do it correctly ?
Any suggestions to make the this part better or more simple would be much appreciated

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <fstream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    /// to find the nodes in each 100*100 gride///
    int x, y, Radio_Range = 80, No_Max = 100;
    int node_degree[100], data[100][2];
    int Total_Degree = 0, Avg_Degree;

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("example.txt");

    int miny = 0, max_y = 99;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int minx = 0, max_x = 99;

        for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k <= 4; k++) {
                x = minx + rand() % (max_x - minx + 1);
                y = miny + rand() % (max_y - miny + 1);
                myfile << x << "  " << y << endl;
            }
            minx = max_x + 1;
            max_x = max_x + 100;
        }

        miny = max_y + 1;
        max_y = max_y + 100;
    }

    ///to finde the node degree//the avg degree//the distance///

    int loop = 0; //Index of array//The line taken from the *.txt source
    string line;
    if (myfile.is_open()) { //Checking if the file can be opened
        while (!myfile.eof()) { //Runs while the file is NOT at the end
            getline(myfile, line); //Gets a single line from example.txt
            data[loop][2] = line; //Saves that line in the array
            loop++;

            for (int i = 0; i < No_Max; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < No_Max; j++) {
                    double distance = sqrt(
                            pow(data[i][0] - data[j][0], 2) + 
                            pow(data[i][1] - data[j][1], 2));

                    if (distance <= Radio_Range) {
                        node_degree[i] = node_degree[i] + 1;
                    }

                    cout << data[i][0] << "-" << data[i][1] << endl;
                    cout << data[j][0] << "-" << data[j][1] << endl;
                    myfile << " The node degree \n" << node_degree[i] << endl;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < No_Max; i++) {
                Total_Degree = Total_Degree + node_degree[i];
                Avg_Degree = Total_Degree / No_Max;
                myfile << " The Avg degree\n" << Avg_Degree << endl;
            }

            myfile.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is like reading a train derailment.  Please format your code, then edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

> `data[loop][2]`

There is no column #2.  Indices in C++ are zero-based.

Answer (score -1):

You would likely need to typecast the data to match the variable type of the array you're assigning it to.